# Undefined reference to class constructor

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

Here's my code:

**menuState.hpp**

```
#ifndef MENU_STATE_HPP
#define MENU_STATE_HPP

#include "state.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class MenuState : public State
{
    public:
        MenuState();

        static void create(StateListener* Parent, const std::string name)
        {
            MenuState* myState = new MenuState();
            myState->parent = Parent;
            Parent->manageState(name, myState);
        }

        void enter();
        void exit();
        void resume();
    private:

};

#endif // MENU_STATE_HPP
```

I'm getting an undefined reference to the constructor when I do `MenuState* myState = new MenuState();` and I'm not sure why because MenuState::MenuState() comes before the create function in the class declaration.

EDIT: I'm also getting the same error to all my sfml functions.

Here's the exact build messages: http://pastebin.com/e819FhPj

I do have the sfml libraries linked and the header path set in my compilers search directories.

Comment: You're missing the definition/implementation, cupcake.

Comment: [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, Sounds tasty.

Comment: @chris it's the longer shelf life.

Comment: menuState.cpp wasn't included in the codeblocks project, hence the error. Didn't notice that >.<

Comment: I'm also getting the same error to all my sfml functions.

Here's the exact build messages: http://pastebin.com/e819FhPj

I do have the sfml libraries linked and the header path set in my compilers search directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always best to show the exact text of the error, but my educated guess is, you are getting a linker error, not a compiler error. Have you actually implemented the constructor anywhere? I bet you haven't.

Comment: menuState.cpp wasn't included in the codeblocks project, hence the error. Didn't notice that >.<

Comment: I'm also getting the same error to all my sfml functions.

Here's the exact build messages: http://pastebin.com/e819FhPj

I do have the sfml libraries linked and the header path set in my compilers search directories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an experience C++ developer but it seems like MenuState constructor is declared but not defined. 
Replace MenuState(); with MenuState(){} should fix the error.